# Notification based on time item in listview

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an arraylist of objects, a member of which is a date/time.
The arraylist and object is used to populate the UI listview.

I would like to send a push notification when the time from the object/listview is approaching system/mobile time (whether its 5, 10 mins or modifiable, doesn't matter).

So i'm familiarizing myself with the Notification Builder, but i'm unsure where to put the logic and how the app will monitor the time and notify when its close.

Any ideas, suggestions on the right path much appreciated

Comment: please if there is a problem with the question, please let me know so I can elaborate, instead of just downvote, i want to learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference, I created a class that extends BroardcastReceiver and used that to handle the alarms from AlarmManager - its all there in the docs but its kinda confusing how everything sits together at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an alarm at a scheduled time and then use an IntentService to capture it once alarm goes off.

In the main activity (lets assume the name is MainActivity, you can create an alarm like this.

```
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity, NotifService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity, 0, intent, 0);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + PERIOD, pi);
    where the PERIOD defines after how much milliseconds you want the alarm to go off.
```

To configure the AlarmManager differently, you can read more about it.

NotifService is what captures the alarm when it goes off. Create a class called NotifService it extends IntentService

```
    public class NotifService extends IntentService {

    public NotifService() {
      super("My service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         //write your code for sending Notification
         Intent intent = new Intent(); 
         intent.setAction("com.xxx.yyy.youractivitytobecalled");
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (getApplicationContext());
        builder.setContentTitle("Your Application Title");
        builder.setContentText("Notification Content");
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setTicker("Your content");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setOngoing(false);
        builder.setPriority(0);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManager notificationManger = (NotificationManager) getSystemService (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManger.notify(1, notification);

    }
    }
```

Register NotifService in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
             fill content here />

    <service android:name=".NotifService" >
    </service>

    </application>
```

Comment: Actually that's an interesting way to look at it. If I'm using a list of items, do you think I should set alarms for each one (assuming they are deleted when triggered) ?

Comment: Why not? It makes sense. You can have a look at Timer and Timer Task as well..If you found my answer useful, please do vote up my answer or accept it.

Comment: hi i havent yet marked this as answered because i've been looking for different ways of doing it - i came across Services.  Can anyone suggest what is more logical for what i'm asking ? thx

Comment: Well in the approach that i suggested, the alarm is calling a service only, of type IntentService. This is the way I have implemented it in one of my applications..may be someone can provide a different solution.